# ASP .NET MVC 5 Edit form depending on role and/or status

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm quite new to MVC and I'm facing an issue how to solve the following problem:  an edit form needs to be updated by different user roles, means each user updates different fields. I'd like to show on top the main information fields (like material#, description, etc.) disabled and below the editable fields.

I'm coming from web forms fields and I solved that in the past by having different web user controls (.ascx). One for main data, second for edit data. Depending on the user role and status of the record (e.g. created, requested, approved) I did load dynamically the web user controls.

Second issue: I don't want to have a separate index page for each user role. Instead, I'd prefer to hide the "Edit" link in case user shall not edit the form (e.g. because it has the status 'requested'). In web forms I solved that by using a listview and within ItemDataBound I replaced the link accordingly.

What is the best practice within MVC area for such scenario?

Comment: Hi there. A number of women in our community sometimes say that every time they see gendered assumptions about software engineers, they feel a bit excluded. I wonder, could you try to avoid adding male-oriented greetings and pronouns in your posts, so as to make for a more welcoming environment? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Partial Views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial) instead of the web user controls. Use a seperate ViewModel for each partial, and compose the main ViewModel from the partial models.

You can check conditions in the Razor markup and render the partials/links accordingly.

For example:

```
public class ReadOnlyDataViewModel {
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
}

public class EditableDataViewModel {
     public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class MainViewModel {
    public ReadOnlyDataViewModel ReadOnlyData { get; set; }
    public EditableDataViewModel EditableData { get; set; }
    public bool HasEditPermission { get; set; }
}
```

_ReadOnlyData.cshtml

```
@model ReadOnlyDataViewModel 
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.CreationDate)
```

_EditableData.cshtml

```
@model EditableDataViewModel 
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name)
```

Different partials can also use the same ViewModel, for example to show the editable data as read only:

_EditableDataReadOnly.cshtml

```
@model EditableDataViewModel 
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Name)
```

Main.cshtml

```
@model MainViewModel 

@Html.Partial("_ReadOnlyData", Model.ReadOnlyData)

@if (Model.HasEditPermisson) {
    @Html.Partial("_EditableData", Model.EditableData)
}
else {
    @Html.Partial("_EditableDataReadOnly", Model.EditableData)
}

@* Conditional link *@
@if (Model.HasEditPermisson) {
    @Url.Action("Edit", "MyController")
}
```

Comment: Georg, thank you very much. This is pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

In MVC, there is something called [partial view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial). Basically, it allows you to create a 'partial' view which can be embedded wherever you want. You can embed different partial views (partial views that contain form in your case) depending on a role and/or status.
If user role is equals to administrator. then `@{ Html.RenderPartial("_AdministratorEditForm"); }` and etc. I hope you got the point.